# h2o.ai H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException: Error: File does not exist

Tags: h2o

Using `h2o` on python in jupyter notebook and getting error message:

```
...
/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h2o/backend/connection.pyc in _process_response(response, save_to)
    723         # Client errors (400 = "Bad Request", 404 = "Not Found", 412 = "Precondition Failed")
    724         if status_code in {400, 404, 412} and isinstance(data, (H2OErrorV3, H2OModelBuilderErrorV3)):
--> 725             raise H2OResponseError(data)
    726 
    727         # Server errors (notably 500 = "Server Error")
H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException: 
Error: File <path to data file I'm trying to import> does not exist.
```

when trying to import data with

```
train = h2o.import_file(path = os.path.realpath("relative path to data file"))
```

Yet the file does in fact exist on the specified path. Why would this be happening?

**Details**

Following `h2o` deeplearning [example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/deeplearning/deeplearning.py) for accessing `h2o` service from python code in a jupyter notebook. Everything works fine up until the [part](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/deeplearning/deeplearning.py#L69) where need to import `.csv` data, eg.

```
spiral = h2o.import_file(path = os.path.realpath("../data/spiral.csv"))
```

At which point the error above is raised. The source code comments that

> # In this case, the cluster is running on our laptops. Data files are imported by their **relative locations** to this notebook.

Yet, when running

```
os.path.exists(os.path.realpath("./data/<my data csv file>"))
```

in the notebook, the response is `true`. So it seems like the relative path is recognized by the python os package*, but there is some problem with the h2o.import_file() method.

What could be going on here? Thanks.

Note: that I'm am using port forwarding from the machine actually running the h2o and jupyter-notebook services with something like:

remote machine:

```
$jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

local machine:

```
$ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 myuser@mnode01
```

* The directory structure is:

```
bin  
data
  |
  |_____ mydata.csv  
include  
lib  
remote-h2o.ipynb
```

**UPDATE**

Think have found the problem. The h2o python [docs](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turan/4/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html) specify that

> The path to the data must be a valid path **for each node** in the H2O cluster. If some node in the H2O cluster cannot see the file, then an exception will be thrown by the H2O cluster.

This raises the question, that does this mean that all of the cluster nodes need to have the same virtualenv (with same absolute path) that I am running the jupyter notebook and holding the data/mydata.csv in?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it by changing the port in the h2o.init(port='XXXXX')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).